# Is VisualSVN Server repository compatible with svn repository I would create on linux?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I'd like to use 
http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

which installs simply on windows. But I'd like to know if I could copy it if needed on a linux server with apache subversion server installed. How can I be sure that the versions of format are the same ?

Comment: Don't copy the plain files over. Perform a dump and restore. While SVN is relatively standardized (at least insofar as a defacto impl.) the format of the back-end database files/store has changed over time and there is no reason why all SVN servers must use the same physical repository layout.

Comment: @user166390 the suggestion is incorrect. Dump-load is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As djechelon says, VisualSVN just uses the standard SVN protocol; you can dump your repos via the Windows command prompt - the following will dump your whole repo and all revisions:

```
svnadmin dump your/repos/path > /your/repo/here.dump
```

Comment: Does VisualSVN ship svndadmin tool too?

Comment: Yup! It puts command line binaries inside the VisualSvn Server folder (under program files); I think there's a link to a command prompt starting in that directory under the VisualSVN Server folder on the Start menu, but I might be wrong...

Answer (score 4):

You can!

SVN is de-facto standard protocol. VisualSVN is 100% SVN-compatible, so it also works with Linux clients

I don't know exactly how to dump a VisualSVN repo, but once you do so you can do svnadmin load from Linux. See if you have a "dump" option in your GUI, or... well... RTFM :)

More info on backup and restore: http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Subversion_backup_and_restore